# React. Redirect by button click in React with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So, I try to understand how can I make right redirection in my app with event clicks? I put the `react-router-dom` redirect logic into the button `event handler`, but it does not work.

What is I'm making wrong?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Preloader from '../Preloader/Preloader'
import preloaderRunner from '../../Modules/PreloaderRunner'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        console.log('Button is cliked!');
        return <Redirect to="/employers" />
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Preloader/>
                <h1>This is the Auth Page!</h1>
                {this.state.navigate === true
                ? <div>
                    <div>You already loggined!</div> 
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Go to the Employers List!</button>
                  </div>
                : <div>
                    <form>
                       // some code...
                    </form>
                </div>}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things returned by a click handler will not be rendered by your component. You have to introduce a new state property that you can set and then render the `<Redirect>` component when that property contains a path to redirect to:

```js
class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false,
            referrer: null,
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        console.log('Button is cliked!');
        this.setState({referrer: '/employers'});
    }

    render() {
        const {referrer} = this.state;
        if (referrer) return <Redirect to={referrer} />;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively instead of rendering your own button with a click handler you could render a `<Link>` component as suggested by @alowsarwar that will do the redirect for you when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe on click you want to take the user to '/employers' . Then you need to use **Link** from the react-router-com. Ideally in React events like '**handleClick**' should change the state not return a JSX (this  is the wrong approach)

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Preloader from '../Preloader/Preloader'
import preloaderRunner from '../../Modules/PreloaderRunner'
import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navigate: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ navigate: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Preloader/>
                <h1>This is the Auth Page!</h1>
                {this.state.navigate === true
                ? <div>
                    <div onClick="this.handleClick">If you want to enable link on some event (Sample test case fyr)</div> 
                    {this.state.navigate ? <Link to='/employers'/> : null}
                  </div>
                : <div>
                    <form>
                       // some code...
                    </form>
                </div>}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginPage;
```